# Arrays & pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

So I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pointer_shift(int *a, int n);

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {100, 101, 102};
    pointer_shift(a1, 3);
}

void pointer_shift(int *a, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i != n - 1; i++) {
        *(a + i) = *(a + i + 1);
    }
}
```

I just want to clarify how the pointers work in this snippet. So pointer_shift takes in 'a', a **pointer to an int,** correct? a1 is passed in to this parameter, and since arrays decay to a pointer to their first element, it works.

First of all, hopefully what I said in the above paragraph is correct. Secondly, what does *(a + i) = *(a + i + 1); actually do? Say we're on the first iteration of the for loop, and i = 0. Then the left side, *a, accesses what, exactly? Does it represent a pointer? I thought * was the dereferencing operator, and accesses the object that a pointer points to... And so then it sets *a = *(a + 1). (a + 1) is the next element in the array, but what exactly does this assignment do, and why?

Thanks!

Comment: The canonical way to write that loop would be `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)`

Comment: `*(a+i)` is equivalent to `a[i]`

Comment: @EdS. would that be `< n` or `< n - 1`?  (I agree normally you run with your loop control, but the given loop terminates when `i == n-1`, not when `i == n`.)

Comment: Well, you're right I suppose because `< n` would run you past the end of the array in this part: `*(a + i + 1);`

Answer (score 2):

It is actually not pointer shift, but value shift, `*(a+i)` is of same effect as `a[i]`, so what it does is `a[i] = a[i+1]`

Answer (score 0):

`*(a + i) = *(a + i + 1);` is copying array elements within the array using a bit of pointer arithmetic.

`*(a + i)` is equivalent to `a[i]`, so the statement is equivalent to `a[i] = a[i + 1];`. The loop is moving the array values "to the left" in the array: `a[0] = a[1]; a[1] = a[2];` and so on.

Your understanding of the function call is correct.

Comment: Okay thanks. So if the statement is equivalent to a[i] = a[i + 1], then how does a[i] POINT TO a[i + 1]? Why does it just get a[i + 1]'s value? I'm still a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to clarify how the pointers work in this snippet. So pointer_shift takes in 'a', a pointer to an int, correct? a1 is passed in to this parameter, and since arrays decay to a pointer to their first element, it works.

Yes, when you pass an array to a function it degrades to a pointer.  An array is not a pointer in an object sense, but it is a pointer in a value sense.  When you pass it to a function its value is passed, i.e., a pointer to the first element.

array indexing is the same as pointer arithmetic, so the last two lines in this snippet are equivalent:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

arr[0] = 10;
*arr = 10;
```

as are these:

```
arr[1] = 20;
*(arr + 1) = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `a + i` is pointer arithmetic, incrementing the memory address stored in `a` by `i` units of the pointer size of `a`. So if a pointer to an `int` takes four bytes on your system, and if the current memory address is, say, `0x1234` the value of `a + 1` would be `0x1238`.

What the asterisk does is dereference that address and access the actual value at that address. If you have `100` stored at `a` or `a[0]`, and `101` stored at `a + 1` or `a[1]`, then `*(a + i) = *(a + i + 1)` replaces `100` with `101` at `a[0]`, for `i = 0`.

Basically, you want to read [this C tutorial on pointers and arrays](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).